# Class method which includes another class method is undefined when setting a variable to be the original class method

Tags: javascript, function, class

Why is the following throwing an error, and how would I go about trying to fix.

```js
class Foo {
  bar() {
   console.log("bar"); 
  }
  fizz() {
   this.bar(); // TypeError: this is undefined
  }
}

let foo = new Foo();
let buzz = foo.fizz;
buzz();
```

Comment: You’re losing the context by assigning the function to `buzz` and calling it as plain `buzz()`.

Comment: @deceze I don't understand why I am losing context, and additionally how would I go about calling `buzz()` without it throwing an error

Comment: Please consult the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Use arrow function:

```js
class Foo {
  bar() {
   console.log("bar"); 
  }
  fizz=()=> {
   this.bar(); // TypeError: this is undefined
  }
}

let foo = new Foo();
let buzz = foo.fizz;
buzz();
```

Comment: This requires _very_ modern browsers to work since it's only been introduced in ES9

Comment: @volt, what are you saying, the class and arrow function concept was there from es6, 2015

Comment: Correct, but that's not what you're using here. Your code relies on [class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields) not just classes and arrow functions.

Comment: the OP is asking why the this keyword is throwing error when he is not directly calling the function, it has nothing to do with the modern browserrs?

Comment: @volt what does the browser support look like for this feature?

Comment: @grahamcracker1234 For popular browsers, MDN says it only works on Chrome (74+) but in my testing It works on the latest Chrome, Firefox and Chromium Edge but results in errors on Safari, IE11, and old Edge.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here @SunilLama. Your example defines `fizz` as a class field / property not as a method of the `Foo` class. That's what's not supported.